# Highly significant t-test statistics, any way to correct this?

Tags: t-test, p-value, adjustment

I have been performing several paired t-test, where I test whether the sample means are different between two groups.

For all of my tests (approx. 30), which all carries 13-14,000 observations, I get a p-value with a significance of 1%. I was wondering if there was any reason to this? I know that as `n` increases, the t-statistic increases monotonically (due to `n` being the root). The t-test is:

[image]

I was wondering if this isn't a potential issue, for my study? I have read somewhere that some people adjusts the p-value through a Minimum Bayesian Factor (MFB). I have tried finding an explain like I'm 5 to understand the basics, but have not been able to. Maybe there are other methods?

Comment: From what you wrote it's not clear why you're concerned. Nothing seems out of ordinary, unless there's something you didn't describe

Comment: I was wondering since I spoke to my thesis supervisor, and he said it is a potential problem, that all my tests are so significant - which as far as I've gathered, comes from the increase in t-statistics as n increases. But isn't this conceptually wrongful - as any test would prove to be significant, just by arbitrarily increasing a sample size?

Comment: Your sample size is quite large. Some would say with 10,000 observation any hypothesis would be rejected. I won't go as far, but the fact that you ran 30 tests and they all rejected on its own merit is not a concern to me. There must be something else your adviser knows about the tests that concerns him.

Comment: Specifically, I was referred to this paper: 'Presidential Address: The Scientific Outlook in Financial Economics', by Campbell R. Harvey. Having read the paper, I understand the overall concept of the minimum Bayes Factor, but not really how to reflect that to my problem. My sample size is, as it is - but he was referring to a way to adjust my p-values to be more "accomodating" to my large sample size.

Comment: Is your supervisor recommending smaller sample sizes? One way forward here is to look at the CI of the difference between means and think what it implies scientifically or practically. Note that if your data are time series then P-values probably need to be corrected for serial dependence, which isn't trivial.

Comment: @NickCox - My data actually does consist of time-series. How would one go about correcting it for serial dependence?

Comment: There really isn't a short answer. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, but sticking to the original point: does the effect size has anything to do with this? As in Cohen's D?

Comment: @Philip, I believe when Gosset developed finite sample statistics techniques, his sample sizes were in tens and at most in hundreds.

Comment: 1. Many posts already on site address this issue. There's no inherent problem; in many common situations nulls are essentially always strictly false and low p-values with false nulls and sufficiently large sample sizes is a natural consequence of [consistent tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)#Tests) (a feature people nearly always agree is desirable -- but then balk when they see it happening).  2. I would be concerned about the assumption of independence given that you have time series; I'd also be quite concerned about omitted variable bias.